# Spring integration: FileInboundAdapter to read oldest files first

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have the following FileInboundAdapter configurations:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileInboundAdapterFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("tmp"))
            .preventDuplicates(true),
            e -> e.id("fileInboundAdapterChannel").autoStartup(true)
                    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
            .channel("fileInboundAdapterResultChannel").get();
}
```

currently, we need to change this to make our own customization of the file adapter in order to start it manually after the SFTP adapter finishes downloading the files to the local directory, in addition to this we need to read the oldest files first as the file names contains the date we need to prioritize reading files with.

the SFTP adapter configurations are as follows:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory())
                            .preserveTimestamp(true)
                            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
                            .remoteDirectory(this.remoteDirectory)
                            .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
                            .localDirectory(new File(this.localFilesDirectory)),
                    e -> e.id("sftpChannel")
                            .autoStartup(false)
                            .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
            .channel("sftpReplyChannel")
            .handle(m -> System.out.println(m.getPayload()))
            .get();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not clear why you need that extra `Files.inboundAdapter()` for the local directory, since an `Sftp.inboundAdapter()` is good one not only to download files from the SFTP, but emit messages with local files as payload. So, you `.channel("sftpReplyChannel")` will get a proper data.

Anyway the `Files.inboundAdapter()` can be configured with the `Comparator<File>`:

```
/**
 * Create a {@link FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec} builder for the {@code FileReadingMessageSource}.
 * @param directory the directory to scan files.
 * @param receptionOrderComparator the {@link Comparator} for ordering file objects.
 * @return the {@link FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec} instance.
 */
public static FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec inboundAdapter(File directory,
        Comparator<File> receptionOrderComparator) {
```

This way you really can order the local files any possible and required way.

Comment: This is some sort of a requirement to have the files downloaded locally first,
but do you think i can remove the Files.inboundAdapter() and make a custom Sftp.inboundAdapter() using the same way of a comparator?

Comment: Yes, sounds like you don't need that `Files.inboundAdapter()`, but you really can use an overloaded `Sftp.inboundAdapter()` which accepts a `Comparator<File>` alongside with the `sftpSessionFactory`.